# Bash loop to get lines in a file, skipping comments and blank lines

Tags: bash

I want to get lines from a file that might look like this

```
# This will be skipped
But this line will not
Nor this one

# this and the above blank line will be skipped
but not this one!
```

The code I have for handling the comments is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts = inventory/hosts

# List hosts we're going to try to connect to
cat $hosts | while read line; do
  case "$line" in \#*) continue ;; esac
        echo $line
done
```

But that doesn't skip the whitespace. Not sure what I need to add. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It also doesn't set the value of a variable named `hosts`. `hosts=inventory/hosts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to do. No loop needed unless you need to do further operations on the remaining lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts="inventory/hosts"

# List hosts we're going to try to connect to
grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' $hosts
```

Comment: That did it, here's the final code:

    grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' $hosts | while read line; do

Answer (score 4):

You can tweak loop like this:

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ -n "$line" && "$line" != [[:blank:]#]* ]] && echo "$line"
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts = inventory/hosts

# List hosts we're going to try to connect to
sed -e '/^\s*$/ d' -e '/^#/ d' $hosts | while read line; do
    echo $line
done
```

Comment: did you try it? Does it work? (I would be surprised if it did, but don't have time to test). Good luck!

Comment: Was missing the file name variable in there, but otherwise it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to skip comments and blank lines, then maybe a simple `sed` command would be enough:

```
$ cat test
# This will be skipped
But this line will not
Nor this one

# this and the above blank line will be skipped
but not this one!
```

Try something like `sed '/^#/d'` to get rid of the comments, and `sed '/^$/d'` to get rid of blank lines.

```
$ sed '/^#/d' test | sed '/^$/d'
But this line will not
Nor this one
but not this one!
```